# Alignment of two equations on LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, align

I'm trying to get two equations aligned via the equals sign, this is my code so far:

```
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 xJ_v(\lambda x)J_v(\mu x) \mathrm{d}x &= \frac{\mu J_v(\lambda)J^{\prime}_v(\mu) - \lambda J_v (\mu)J^{\prime}_v(\lambda)}{\lambda^2 - \mu^2}
\\[5mm]
\int_0^1 x[J_v(\lambda x)]^2 \mathrm{d}x &= [J_{v+1}(\lambda)]^2 + \left( \frac{\lambda^2 - v^2}{2 \lambda^2} \right)[J_v(\lambda)]^2,
\end{align}
```

I've tried using & and also \begin{align} but it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: If you used align and the equations aren't aligning, you have improperly placed the alignment character & or haven't placed it at all.

Comment: @dustin -- your edit made the code work.  the problem was that the end of the first line was marked with `\[5mm]` where a double backslash was needed.  you edited in the second backslash when you reformatted the code.

Comment: @barbarabeeton his post on math.stackexchange was off with that code. I didnt check the mathjx formatting. I just assumed a missing or misplaced & when I commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the displayed expression below, select *Show Math As*, and then select *TeX Commands*.

```
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 xJ_v(\lambda x)J_v(\mu x) \mathrm{d}x &= \frac{\mu J_v(\lambda)J^{\prime}_v(\mu) - \lambda J_v (\mu)J^{\prime}_v(\lambda)}{\lambda^2 - \mu^2}\;,\\\\
\int_0^1 x[J_v(\lambda x)]^2 \mathrm{d}x &= [J_{v+1}(\lambda)]^2 + \left( \frac{\lambda^2 - v^2}{2 \lambda^2} \right)[J_v(\lambda)]^2\;,
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general to align equations, it goes like:

```
Document text here.
\begin{align}
  \label{eq1} x^2 & = y^2 \\
  \label{eq2} x^2 & = y^2 \\
  \label{eq3} x^2 & = y^2
\end{align}
```

If you want the equations to not be numbered, take out the label commands and don't write the * at the end of align. Note that you don't need to use other commands to enter and exit the math environment, such as $$ or the commands

`\begin{equation}`

`\end{equation}`

Comment: Taking out `\label` doesn't stop numbering in `LaTeX`. Maybe on MathJax but this is not the case in general. To stop numbering, one would use `\begin{align*}` variant.

Comment: Or use the command \notag